# Windows > 一時ファイル > 後で自動的に消えてくれるもの

Tags: windows

```
開発環境: C++ Builder XE4
```

Windows (7/8.1)において、一時ファイルを作成して利用したいと考えています。

使用イメージは以下です。
1. 自作ソフトからhtmlファイル（一部ファイル）を作成
2. 自作ソフトからChrome(またはIE)を起動し、htmlファイルを表示
3. ユーザがhtmlファイル閲覧を終えるとブラウザを閉じる

1から3のすべてを自作で管理している場合は、３の処理が終了次第、一時ファイルを削除すればいいのですが、3でブラウザにコントロールを渡しているため、いつ終了したかの判断は自作ソフト側ではできません。

そこで、一時ファイルが自動的に削除される方法があれば、と考えています。

Windowsのシステムでは、ある特定のフォルダにファイルを置いておけば自動的に削除される、というようなフォルダはありましたでしょうか？ (linuxの/tmpのようなもの).

Comment: 保険としてOSのサポートがあるにこしたことはないですが、起動するのがブラウザであれば、起動時に一度ファイルを読んだ後はリロードでもしないかぎりファイルを見に行きませんので、ブラウザ起動後、30秒とかの定時間で消してしまっても問題ないと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ブラウザのキャッシュ（？）機能を利用するというのですね。それも手ですね。
案ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイル作成時に`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`を指定する、という回答がついていますが手元で試した範囲ではこの方法は動かなかったので別案を回答しておきます。

まず、Linuxの`/tmp`が自動で消えるのは、単に「古いファイルを消す」という処理が定期的に走っているからです。ただしこれは当たり前のことではなく、ディストリビューションによって異なります。ということで、/tmpに一時ファイルを置いたからと行って確実に消えるというものでもありません。

…というレベルで確実でなくてもよいがある程度消したい、という話でしたら、ファイル名のプレフィクス/ポストフィクスやサブフォルダに保存するなど自分が作った一時ファイルだということがわかる工夫をして、起動時に*前回までに作られたファイル*を消すという考え方もあります。

ある程度確実に一時的にファイルを消したいのであれば、呼び出した別プログラムの終了を待つ小さなプロセスを残しておく、という方法が考えられます。

Comment: そうですね、クローズ時に消せる機能はあるものの、質問のように別プロセスに読み込ませる用途だと難しそうですね。通常は`FILE_SHARE_DELETE`を付けないでしょうし。そこまで確認できていませんでした。

Comment: FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSEでの処理の確認と別の案の掲示ありがとうございます。
ファイルを消す処理を呼び出し元のプログラムか別プロセスで処理する方法で実装を検討してみます。

Answer (score 4):

[CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)にはFILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSEフラグが存在します。これを指定するとファイルを作成したプロセス（この場合は自作ソフト）の終了時にそのファイルが自動的に削除されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSEというのは知りまでした。使ってみます。

Comment: FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSEを使うにはファイル共有モード(FILE_SHARE_*)の指定が悩ましいので(ファイルを作る側もそれを開く側も)、どのようなFILE_SHARE_*を指定すれば目的が達せられるかも書いてあるとよりよい回答になるでしょう。(簡単に試してみたのですが、適切なFILE_SHARE_*の組み合わせが見つからず、FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSEを指定して作成したファイルをブラウザに開かせることはできませんでした)

Comment: @suzukis FILE_SHARE_*などで考慮すべき点があるのですね。情報ありがとうございます。ブラウザを開かないところまで試していただき感謝です。

Answer (score 2):

<strike>MoveFile</strike>MoveFileEx APIでMOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOTを指定すれば、再起動時にファイルを削除するということは出来ます。linuxの/tmpの様に定期的に削除する設定はないので、同様というわけにはいきませんが。

確実なのは自アプリケーション用にフォルダを作成。タイムスタンプの古いファイルを自動的に削除するプログラムをタスクに登録して定期的に削除することです。これなら/tmpど同様の機能を実現できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 MoveFile APIというのもあるのですね。参考になります。

Comment: MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOTを指定できるのは、[MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240.aspx)ですよ。

Comment: 失礼しました。修正させていただきました。